# Clock keeper story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

Been bugging me for years.

A man is keeping a giant clock running.  He doesn't remember his past or how he got to be where he is.  He is badly dressed, badly fed and exhausted by what seems like his pointless task.  Frustrated by his awful life, he destroys the clock - and time stops.

What is it called, and who wrote it?

Think I read it back in the 1960s so it's definitely not recent.

Comment: I seem to remember that one as well. Ifrc there was a pile of skeletons, some almost dust, and a much more recent mouldering corpse lying atop the pile. All his predecessors. Can't remember much more. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

This is *The Great Clock* by Langdon Jones. I read it in *The Time Traveler's Almanac* edited by the VanderMeers. It was first published in *New Worlds Quarterly* March 1966.

He doesn't remember his past or how he got to be where he is.

> What was his life before he came here? Who was he? He could not
> remember. Nor could he remember how long he had been here.

He is badly fed,

> He settled down listlessly and began to spoon the mash into his mouth.
> It was completely tasteless...

and exhausted,

> His body strained with the effort. Surely, at one time it had all been
> easier...
>
> His next task was the Winding, and he tried not to think of this. It
> was a task that took about an hour of his time every day, and left him
> a weak, trembling old man.

There is a pile of skeletons

> Then he turned and walked back past the pile of bones in the other
> corner, skulls like large pieces of yellow putty, twigs of ribs, half
> buried by dust...

He destroys the Clock

> With all his strength he swung the hammer in a low arc and relaxed
> only as it smashed into the wheel. ... "I've killed you," he said.

and time stops.

> ... it was everybody else's last sight, too. ... after that, there was
> no time to see anything.

Comment: Great answer, but the magazine title was just [*New Worlds*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?109871+c), not *New Worlds Quarterly*, and it was on a monthly publication schedule.

Comment: That part of my answer was based on the copyright information in the back of *Time Traveler's Almanac*. Perhaps, as with some of Gernsback's titles, there was a quarterly special in addition to the monthlies.

Comment: If there was a magazine titled *New Worlds Quarterly*, the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/directory.cgi?magazine+ne) doesn't know about it. Seems more likely to me that the copyright information in that anthology is inaccurate. Also, "March 1966" is an unusual way to date a quarterly; issues of Gernsback's *Amazing Stories Quarterly* and *Wonder Stories Quarterly* were dated Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter.

Comment: Moreover, since the story definitely appeared in the March 1966 issue of *New Worlds*, it is very unlikely that it would appear simultaneously in *New Worlds Quarterly* even if the latter title existed.